# Passing a vector by reference through a function

Tags: c++, vector

I am getting a "type/value mismatch at argument 1" error on declaring the parameters of fillVector. Is there a namespace issue or just bad syntax somewhere?

```
#ifndef VECTOR_OBJECTS_H_INCLUDED
#define VECTOR_OBJECTS_H_INCLUDED


void fillVector(vector<Chest> &newChest, int x, int y)
{

ifstream load_chest;
load_chest.open("\\chest_item_inputs.txt");
char input = NULL;
int x_count = NULL;
int y_count = NULL;

while(input != 0)
{
load_chest >> input;
    if(input = '.')
    {
    x_count++;
    }
    if(input = 'C')
    {
    x = x_count;
    y = y_count;
    Chest newChest(x_count, y_count);
    newChest.pushback(newChest);
    }
    if(input = 80)
    {
    x_count = 0;
    y_count++;
    }
} load_chest.seekg (0, load_chest.beg);
}
}

#endif // VECTOR_OBJECTS_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: Presumably VectorObjects.h has a declaration of `fillVector` in it. Can we see it? And can we see the full error? Does `Chest` have a default constructor?

Comment: I thought that was the declaration?? error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector'|

Comment: Apologies. My mistake. I for some reason we thought we were looking at VectorObjects.cpp.

Comment: Is `Chest` a class or a template? If it's a template, you need to give it template arguments.

Comment: No worries! How do I determine the difference between template or class?

Comment: If `Chest` is a class template, it begins with `template <something here> class Chest ...`. If it's just a class, it begins with only `class Chest ...`.

Comment: It's just a class in this case.

Comment: Oh I found it! I was using the class object and not the class name to define the function. Silly me! Thanks anyways!!

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer so other people may find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

You have a local variable with the same name as the argument:

```
void fillVector(vector<Chest> &newChest, int x, int y) {
   ...
   Chest newChest(x_count, y_count);
   newChest.pushback(newChest);
   ...
}
```